# How to name a class that wraps several primitive types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming-conventions

I have a naming problem for some of my classes. I need to wrap some primitive .net types into a class like the following. There will be about 20 of such classes.

(The naming is crap, of course. Just for a demonstrative purpose)

```
public class Int32Single
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Int32Double
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public int Value2 { get; set; }

}

public class DoubleSingle
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can't use a generic approach for this. 
How should I name such wrapper classes, where each class name should provide the necessary information which primite types are wrapped and in which quantity?

It might also be possible that I have class that contains mixed primite types.

Comment: Why can't you use a generic approach for this? Or just use Tuple if you're using .NET 4?

Comment: `DoubleSingle`, now if that ain't a melon-scratcher...

Comment: If you aren't writing universal framework, that everyone will use, then you are creating those classes for some known purpose. So what is the purpose of this classes?

Comment: Yes, these classes won't be used in a framework. For this project I'm forced to create non-generic classes. Each property will be decorated with different attributes. These objects will the created and filled with reflection from a sort of dynamic database structure. These objects are models in a satellite assembly and are consumed by a Winforms and an ASP.Net application with 3rd party controls that require such non-generic objects for their databindings. I'm sorry I can't discuss the purpose any further, because of my NDA. I'm just trying to make the best out of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a very good idea at all.  You have both the `Tuple` class and a standard `array` available, that both make more sense in any conceivable use case.  However, that doesn't answer your question, so...

The most intuitive name for a wrapper class would follow the convention of `{type-name}Wrapper`, or for example, `Int32Wrapper`.  In your case, the wrapped object is a primitive type, so makes sense to call the class a ["Tuple"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).  Since you want to specify the size of the Tuple in your class name, `{primitive-type-name}{size}Tuple` seems like the most intuitive naming convention but this causes several problems.

- The natural language used to describe Tuples create ambiguity (such as `Single` and `Double` because they conflict with the Type names). (e.g. `DoubleDouble` is bad)
- Integers are used in the naming of some primitive types so this could cause ambiguity. (e.g. `Int322Tuple` is bad).

We can't move the size to the beginning such as `2Int32Tuple` because integers are not valid characters to begin a class name.  So, There are two approaches that I think could work.

I think your best bet to get around these constraints, is to use a `{primitive-type-name}{text-represented-size}Tuple` convention.  (e.g. `Int32TwoTuple` or `DoubleTwoTuple`).  This convention expresses the contents of the wrapper class without ambiguity, so it seems like a good approach.  In addition the name begins with the primitive type name, so, if you have a lot of these classes, it will be easier for your IntelliSense to fill in the correct class name, and it will alphabetically be listed next to the primitive type that is being wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Generics can help you out here:

```
public class WrapTwo<T>
{
    public T Value1 { get; set; }
    public T Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class WrapOne<T>
{
    public T Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

And have you considered the [`Tuple` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)?

Comment: They can also contain mixed types.

Answer (score 0):

`OneInt32`, `TwoInt32s`, `TwoDoubles`? Doesn't sound great.

Tuples? http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple

Answer (score 0):

I don't very fond of Tuples or arrays, because both don't tell much about their purpose. Well, I use them. But mostly as internal members of classes, local variables, or with 3rd party/legacy code.

Back to naming. Compare:

```
Tuple<int,int> a = Tuple.Create(10,10);
Int32Double b = new Int32Double(15, 15);
WrapTwo<int> c = new WrapTwo<int>(20, 20);
```

With

```
Point a = new Point(10, 10);
Vertex b = new Vertex(15, 15);
```

One can argue, that 'a' is not good name for variable (and suggest to use 'pointA' instead). But I think it's pretty good in context of geometry application.

Not just type name and creation code looks obscure, but consider type fields names:

```
a.X = 20;
b.Value1 = 20;
```

So, I think you need some self-descriptive type in context of your application domain.